# System.Drawing.RectangleF : Persisting in Application Settings

Tags: settings, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm trying to persist a `RectangleF` in *Application settings*, but it produces error message:

> Type 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' is not defined.

I can save a string, and then parse to float, but I can't find an explanation to this:

[image: trying to save in Visual Studio]